# R - ggplot lines and columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a chart that one series is a column and the other is a line with points. When I plot the data using the code below, it plots the way I want. However, there is no legend in the chart. Is there a way to force the legend to appear?

Adding the `show.legend = T` and the `group = xxx` makes no difference.

```
data <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c(1, 2, 3),
  C = c(2, 3, 4)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = A)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = C)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = B))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty common stumbling block in ggplot2 and can seem confusing until you get used to it. ggplot2 expects data to be in a "long" format rather than a "wide" format. So in this example, I assume you consider "C" and "B" to be distinct groups you want labelled in a legend. In that case, you need those data sets "stacked" with a variable that distinguishes them taking values "C" and "B". Then you'd map that variable to color or something which will generate a legend.

Comment: I understand that this is how it is supposed to be. However, if I stack my data in such a manner, both series would appear as either lines or columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the same data structure, but it is still awkward, since ggplot doesn't really "want" you to do this (map aesthetics to things that aren't really "real" aesthetics);

```
ggplot(data = data,aes(x = A)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = C,color = "C")) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = B,color = "B",fill = "B"),fill = "blue") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("C" = "red","B" = "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("C" = "red","B" = "blue")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

What you're trying to accomplish here falls more closely under what ggplot would consider "annotation", i.e. you have two very disparate elements (a line and some bars) and I would typically add annotations in the graph labelling them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution that is not very elegant, but works for my case.

```
data.2 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  D = c('B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  B = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA),
  C = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 4)
)

data.2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y = C, col = D, fill = D)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_col(aes(y = B)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'red'), breaks = c('B', 'C')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('grey', 'transparent'), breaks = c('B', 'C'))
```

[image]